# Using a negative exponent

Tags: python, exponent

This is the problem I'm working on

[image]

This is my code

```
p = int(input('Enter the amount of the loan: '))
r = float(input('Enter the interest rate: '))
d = int(input('Enter the length of loan in months: '))
if p > 0 and r > 0 and d > 0:
    m_payment = (p*r)/(1-(1+r) ** 1/d)
    t_interest = d*m_payment-p
else:
    print('Enter a postive number')
print('Monthly payment: ${0:.2f}'.format( m_payment))
print('Total interest paid: ${0:.2f}'.format(t_interest))
```

Am I correctly inputting the exponent?

Comment: You didn't say what the problem is.

Comment: Operator precedence doesn't care about how many spaces you use. The spaces on either side of `**` don't change its precedence.

Comment: You don't have a negative exponent. You did `1/d`, not `-d`, plus `d > 0` according to the conditional

Comment: I believe what you really want is `m_payment = (p*r)/(1-1/(1+r)**d)`.

Comment: The problem is attached. Isn't a negative exponent just a number taken to the 1/n power?

Comment: No, you are confusing it with a^(-b) = 1/(a^b)

Comment: That would be the n-th root. `x ^ 1/2` like `sqrt(x)`. Not `x^-2`

Comment: @Jeremy `"r is the monthly interest rate (annual rate divided by 12)"`, so the user inputs the `annual rate` and you just need to convert that to a `monthly rate`, divide `r` by `12`, i.e. `r = float(input('Enter the interest rate: '))/12.`

Comment: If you think a negative exponent is a number to the `1/n` power, your question is really about math and not programming.

Answer (score 2):

1) Formula uses `n`, not `d`, so why not use `n`?

Anyway...

> Am I correctly inputting the exponent?

Did you get the output given as shown? You can use a normal calculator to verify those numbers.

---

That being said, if you read the question carefully, you are initially inputting "annual interest", not `r`. The instructions say that `r` is annual interest over 12.

So here is that adjustment to your code.

```
p = annual_interest = n = -1
while True:
  p = int(input('Enter the amount of the loan: '))
  annual_interest = float(input('Enter the interest rate: '))
  n = int(input('Enter the length of loan in months: '))
  if p <= 0 or annual_interest <= 0 or n <= 0:
    print('Enter a postive number')
  else:
    break

r = annual_interest / (12 * 100)  # this needs to be a decimal percentage
```

Then, `1/n` is not a negative exponent, it is the N-th root. You can just put a negative exponent in Python, no need to try to think you can re-write it any differently.

```
monthly_payment = (p * r) / (1 - ((1 + r) ** -n))
interest = n * monthly_payment - p
```

Answer (score 0):

No. you are not using the exponent correctly.
The formula clearly states that you have to use a **negative** expononent, but you are trying to get the dth-root.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to only be in the handling of the "annual interest rate" as a "monthly interest rate" converted to a decimal percentage, and the exponent should remain as an integer, only negated.

Keeping your code close to as it is:

```
p = int(input('Enter the amount of the loan: '))
r = float(input('Enter the interest rate: '))
d = int(input('Enter the length of loan in months: '))

mr = (r/100)/12 # convert annual interest rate to a decimal monthly interest rate

if p > 0 and r > 0 and d > 0:
    m_payment = (p*mr)/(1-((1+mr) ** -d))
    t_interest = d*m_payment-p
else:
    print('Enter a postive number')
print('Monthly payment: ${0:.2f}'.format( m_payment))
print('Total interest paid: ${0:,.2f}'.format(round(t_interest))) # given answer appears rounded
```

demo:

```
Enter the amount of the loan: 18000
Enter the interest rate: 5.25
Enter the length of loan in months: 60
Monthly payment: $341.75
Total interest paid: $2,505.00
```

Comment: No worries, I didn't read it carefully at first either, as you can see it took me a long time to figure it out... and the purpose of that textbook-problem may have just been to solve that. It also helped us all brush up on our basic math concepts too. :) Hope it helped.